# Pandas iterating through index to find a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe of experimental data. I have a Multi index that define each samples (A,B) with the data in columns x,y,z:

```
 A   B    x    y     z
0.1  0.1  0.1   0   -1
0.1. 0.1  0.2  -5    0
0.1  0.1  0.4 -10    0 
0.1  0.2  0.6   0   -1
0.1  0.2  0.3  -4 -0.4
0.1  0.2  0.1  -9    0
0.1  0.5  0.2   0    0
0.1  0.5  0.4  -2    0
0.1  0.5  0.3  -5    0
0.2  0.1  0.2  -1   -1
0.2  0.1  0.1  -2   -2
0.2  0.1  0.4  -3    0

...
```

I have a complicated condition to fill but essentially:

- How do I iterate through each value of A and B, to find the max value of column y where the value of column z = 0, and then return a df of all the rows that fulfil this condition

Expected output:

```
 A   B    x    y     z

0.1. 0.1  0.2  -5   0
0.1  0.2  0.1  -9   0
0.1  0.5  0.2   0   0
0.2  0.1  0.4  -3   0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly post your expected output, based on the shared data

Comment: sorry, just added

Comment: Are `A, B` columns in the dataframe or the dataframe index?

Comment: Also there are some `.` after the numbers in the some columns? Are these intentionally added or just a typo?

Comment: A,B are the df index and x,y,z are the data.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
df.loc[df[df["z"] == 0].groupby(["A","B"])['y'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works, I dont want the maximum index value rather the maximum y value for each index. I found a version of this works with .max

'output=(df.loc[df['z']==0]).groupby(['A','B'])['y'].max()'

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df['z'] == 0) & (df['y'] == df['y'].max())]
```

Comment: kindly recheck your code. I dont think it gives the right result

Answer (score 0):

`output=(df.loc[df['z']==0]).groupby(['A','B'])['y'].max()`

Thanks to Narendra Prasath for pointing me in the right direction.